# How can I add new packages to archive.ubuntu.com?

Tags: package-management, software-installation, archive

I found that some of the software downloaded by "apt-get" is now out of date. I compiled the new versions into .deb packages. Now, how can I add them into the software center or archive.ubuntu.com? I just want to make everyone convenient.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly if this is a popular program expect the update to come shortly.

If not then packaging.ubuntu.com is your friend especially [This guide for the process of submitting an [updated] package](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MOTU/Packages/REVU)

As stated in the meantime you can [make a PPA instead](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA)

Here is a similar question: [Outdated package in repo](https://askubuntu.com/questions/562815/outdated-package-in-repo)